# What is the meaning of "MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY" Message?

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-analyst

I am trying to run ST_Intersection function.

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(ST_Point(42.729123082000058,-96.619302355999992), ST_Point(42.72899715300008,-96.619410439999967))) FROM clu_08aug;

I am getting Resultset with the "MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY".

Can someone help me what does it means?

Dharmesh

Answer (score 3):

It means the result of the intersection is an empty geometry (the points don't intersect). It's still a geometry collection but it just don't have any geometry object in it.